# Is there a way to generate YAML instead of JSON CloudFormation templates using the Serverless Framework?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

The Serverless framework is such a great tool. I use it wherever possible.

I would like to know if there is a way to update the `serverless.yml` file to output `yaml` instead of `json` when generating CloudFormation templates. In the `.serverless` folder they are in `json` format but would really be great if they can be auto-generated to `yaml` instead.

I would not prefer to use great tools like https://www.json2yaml.com/

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's always a way but the simple end-user answer is no.

The `serverless-framework` has a naming strategy file per provider and for AWS its hard-coded to `cloudformation-template-[create|update]-stack.json`. When the file writer does its job it looks at the extension and runs the JSON writer.

However as per [the AWS naming file](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/plugins/aws/lib/naming.js) in their repo, they've made it available to be modified by writing a custom plugin. As long as your plugin changed the naming strategy to anything that ends in `.yml` the file writing service will switch to a YAML writing strategy.